# Difference Between The Transisor Denotations V(th) and V(tn)

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt

I have seen these values V(th) and V(tn) used interchangeably as the transistor 'threshold voltage' but have also seen them used together on the same diagram seemingly representing differnt things. (I do not have such a diagram available to show you).

If these variables are the same, or different in any way, for both BJT and MOSFET transistors, please explain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V(th) is general whereas V(tn) is a little more specific.

V(th) is just the threshold voltage.
V(tn) is threshold voltage of an nmos.
V(tp) would be the threshold of a pmos.

Note that BJT's are usually spoken of as current devices so they aren't usually talked about as having a threshold voltage. Incidently, they often have a Vbe (voltage base-emitter) of about 0.7V. BJT's have a \$V_T\$ which is the thermal voltage which is about 25mV: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant#Role_in_semiconductor_physics:_the_thermal_voltage

Lastly, don't be surprised with typos in textbooks on Vth, Vtn, and Vtp. Those always make it even more confusing...